# EBIT(DA) and R&D expenses

Tags: accounting

If a company says it's EBIT(DA) margin was, say, 15%, has the company already deducted:

1. their R&D expenses (mostly thinking about wages here) and/or
2. investments in research or production infrastructure?

Does it matter whether we're talking about EBIT or EBITDA here?

The background to my question is that a company told me that their very ambitious EBITDA margin is owed to their need for investing into R&D, which only makes sense to me if the answer to both the above questions is 'no'.

Comment: Hi, welcome to economics.se. At economics.se accounting is considered off topic (see our help center) so this question is being migrated to personal finance and money stack where might be more on topic

Comment: Given that it is tricial to look uip what is excluded in EBIT and EBITDA - what is left on the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let's answer - what is 'EBIT(DA)'?

**Earnings** (aka 'net income')

**Before**

**Interest** [paid to debtholders on outstanding debt]

**Taxes** [typically income / 'direct' taxes only, ie: the company wouldn't typically remove VAT or similar taxes]

**= EBIT**

Then also remove
**Depreciation** [annual expense taken for a portion of the value of physical assets]

**Amortization** [annual expense taken for a portion of the value of *intangible* assets]

**=EBITDA**

In some cases, research costs may be taken as an expense during the year, so the very first line, Net Income, would already have been reduced by the amount of research costs. In some cases, research costs might be 'capitalized', meaning they are not immediately deducted, instead they are booked as 'Research Assets' [or something like that], and then they are amortized over the anticipated useful life of the project. Whether any given cost is 'capitalized' or 'expensed' will depend on the rules for the accounting system that the company follows [US public companies follow US GAAP; most other public companies follow IFRS, and private companies often have a wide range of choices, not all of which are as stringent at requiring recording to be reasonable].

So it is quite possible that a company could project a very high relative EBITDA or EBIT, if they expect to capitalize much of their research costs. [In such a case, EBITDA would be higher than EBIT, because EBITDA would also get to exclude the partial annual amortization of those research costs]. Does this accounting treatment make the company more profitable? No. Accounting treatment exists only to describe the underlying economics - accounting choices do not affect how the company operates, just how some people might perceive it.

**The question you have to ask yourself is: do you believe the company when they explain this to you, and do you feel comfortable enough to take action based on what they are telling you?** Ask the company to defend its own position, to the point that you understand it. If you can't understand what they're telling you, it implies perhaps you are in over your head, or perhaps they are pulling out BS explanations from thin air.